# How to read specific rows on excel base from a data on one of its column using Java

Tags: java

I have an excel with a format just like below example:

```
FileName,Type,Size,DateModified,Completed,Count
File1,text,111,04/22/2014,Yes,1
File2,text,222,04/23/2014,No,2
File3,word,333,04/24/2014,No,3
File4,excel,444,04/24/2014,Yes,4
File5,ppoint,555,04/25/2014,Yes,5
```

I have a program that reads the excel file by row then by the row's column. But what I needed to be printed are only the rows with a specific date. For this example, I wanted to print the rows that have a DateModified of 04/24/2014, but I couldn't find a way to filter them or create a condition.

I tried filtering by using the column DateModified but can't find a way that when it detected the desired date, it will still print the whole row from column 1.

Java code:

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator(); 

while( rows.hasNext() ) {   
    HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
    System.out.println("\n");
    Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

    while( cells.hasNext() ) {
        HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();

               //missing condition

            if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING==cell.getCellType()) {
                System.out.print( cell.getStringCellValue()+"     " );
            } else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC==cell.getCellType()) {
                System.out.print( cell.getNumericCellValue()+"     "+cell.getColumnIndex() );
            } else if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN==cell.getCellType()) {
                System.out.print( cell.getBooleanCellValue()+"     " );
            } else if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK==cell.getCellType());
                System.out.print( "BLANK     " );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont Print the cell value as soon as you found.
Rather append into StringBuilder and finally print only if condition matches.

Like this

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
          while( rows.hasNext() ) {   
                HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
                System.out.println("\n");
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
                boolean isValidRow = true;
                while( cells.hasNext() ) {
                    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();

                   //missing condition
                    if (condition match){
                        isValidRow = false;
                        break;
                    }

                    if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING==cell.getCellType()) {
                        builder.append( cell.getStringCellValue()+"     " );
                    } else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC==cell.getCellType()) {
                        builder.append( cell.getNumericCellValue()+"     "+cell.getColumnIndex() );
                    } else if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN==cell.getCellType()) {
                        builder.append( cell.getBooleanCellValue()+"     " );
                    } else if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK==cell.getCellType());
                    builder.append( "BLANK     " );
                }
                if (isValidRow){
                    System.out.println(builder.toString());

                }
                builder.setLength(0);
          }
```

UPDATE
Note** . If you know the extact position of the cell where you want to check.

you can check like this also.

```
HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) row.getCell(3);
if ( "04/24/2014".equals(cell.getStringCellValue())){
    Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
                while( cells.hasNext() ) {
                    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();

                   //missing condition

                    if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING==cell.getCellType()) {
                        builder.append( cell.getStringCellValue()+"     " );
                    } else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC==cell.getCellType()) {
                        builder.append( cell.getNumericCellValue()+"     "+cell.getColumnIndex() );
                    } else if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN==cell.getCellType()) {
                        builder.append( cell.getBooleanCellValue()+"     " );
                    } else if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK==cell.getCellType());
                    builder.append( "BLANK     " );
                }

}
```